# how to query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The Data:

```
[{        
                    "shop_ID" : "ABCD",
                    "plan" : 2,
                    "planType" : 2,
                    "goods_id" : "9612",
                    "category" : "1",
                    "keywords" : [
                        {
                            "keyword" : "lianyiqun",
                            "price" : 3.12,
                            "score" : 9
                        },
                        {
                            "keyword" : "nvzhuang",
                            "price" : 6.57,
                            "score" : 6
                        },
                        {
                            "keyword" : "chunzhuang",
                            "price" : 5.55,
                            "score" : 8
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "shop_ID" : "ABCD",
                    "plan" : 2,
                    "planType" : 2,
                    "goods_id" : "5078",
                    "category" : "1",
                    "keywords" : [
                        {
                            "keyword" : "lianyiqun",
                            "price" : 9.26,
                            "score" : 8
                        },
                        {
                            "keyword" : "nvzhuang",
                            "price" : 4.52,
                            "score" : 9
                        }
                    ]
                }]
```

I had used the command query:

db.test.find({"keywords" : { $elemMatch: {"score":{"$gte":8}} } })

the result was not right,it's all documents.

And, use the command
db.test.find({"keywords."score":{"$gte":8}})

the result is same.

I want the query result like this for the first document:

```
{        
                        "shop_ID" : "ABCD",
                        "plan" : 2,
                        "planType" : 2,
                        "goods_id" : "9612",
                        "category" : "1",
                        "keywords" : [
                            {
                                "keyword" : "lianyiqun",
                                "price" : 3.12,
                                "score" : 9
                            },
                            {
                                "keyword" : "chunzhuang",
                                "price" : 5.55,
                                "score" : 8
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

How to query inner-documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator which will return from each array ONE element that matches your condition:

```
db.test.find( { } , 
              { keywords: { $elemMatch: { score: { $gte: 8 } } } } 
            )
```

To return all elements in your subdocument with the score >= 8, you can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/):

```
 db.test.aggregate ( [ { $unwind: "$keywords" },
                       { $match: { "keywords.score" : { $gte: 8 } } } 
                     ] )
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks, Kay. But I have another requirement, If I want use this in mapreduce operation, but the db.collection.mapReduce() function don't support the aggregate. If I write like this:db.test.mapReduce(
                     mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     { out: "map_reduce_test",
                       query: [{$unwind:"$keywords"},{ $match: { "keywords.score" : { $gte: 8 } } } ],
                     }
                   ),the output is :map reduce failed:{
 "errmsg" : "exception: query has to be blank or an Object",
 "code" : 13608,
 "ok" : 0